# Program not opening after being compiled

Tags: c++, windows, cygwin

Yesterday I was playing around with an IRC bot in C++. It compiled and worked just fine, the only thing it really did was say "pong" whenever it saw "ping".

Today I tried to implement a random facts bit of code. I compiled it in cygwin using

```
g++ -o ircbot.exe main.cpp bot.h bot.cpp
```

Now when I try to open it, it tells me "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the file."

After thinking I'd done something wrong I went back, commented out all of the changes I made, tried to compile it again, and it gives the same Windows error. I'm not quite sure where I went wrong here, has anyone had anything similar happen?

Quick update, when I changed the sharing state on Windows to `share with homegroup` it told me the version I was running was not compatible with my version of Windows and to check whether or not it was in 32-bit or 64-bit. I have no idea what it's up to, this is the strangest issue I've had programming. I'll give it a shot in Linux and see if it pulls any silly business.

Comment: Do you have antivirus software or an overprotective systems administrator? neither one like it when you send/receive data over the network without their knowledge.

Comment: Yes, but I added the program as an exception. Quick note, I copy/pasted the files into a different Visual Studio project and compiled those, which seemed to work. Not sure why though.

Comment: Make sure your old `ircbot` program is no longer running.

Comment: I'd restarted my computer since the first time I'd run it and checked my processes to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on Linux, but since you are using cygwin and the problem is so similar it might be the same thing.

I compiled a C++ program into a 32 bit executable on my 64 bit machine. Trying to execute gave me a "File not found" message.

Turns out it failed because I didn't have the 32 bit version of the libraries that my program needed. For some reason the linker did not catch it.

Try passing -m32 or -m64, depending on your machine's architecture.

Comment: I'll give this a shot on a laptop in a bit.  
For now, compiling on Linux is giving me absolutely no issues, and this isn't necessarily a big project. Thanks for the help.